# Sending Value or Variable

Tags: php

I'm Creating Export PHP page.
And Every time i export file the output only is every after space.

```
if(isset($_POST["exports"]))
{
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output1 = fopen("php://output", "w");
fputcsv($output1, array('Pcbid'));
$output = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jopcbid");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output))
{
fputcsv($output1, $row);
}
fclose($output1);
}
```

Example I have "Romeo Juliet Ramon" My output only is "Romeo"

Comment: My table is Datatype Text

Comment: add some enclosure quotes in fputcsv()

Comment: how please give me sample thanks

Comment: please read the manual page for functions you are using